# Let $X$ be an affine variety and U ⊆ X a dense open set. Then dim X \ U < dim X.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

Let $X$ be an affine variety.

**Definition**: Let $X$ be an irreducible affine variety and $C(X)$ its field of rational functions. Then the dimension of $X$ is defined by
$$
\mathrm{dim} X := \mathrm{tdeg}_\mathbb{C} C(X)
$$
where $\mathrm{tdeg}$ denotes the transcendence degree of the field extension $C(X)/ \mathbb{C}$.
If $X$ is reducible and $X=\cup X_i$ its irreducible decomposition then
$$
\mathrm{dim} X := \max \mathrm{dim} X_i .
$$

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $U ⊆ X$ be a dense open set. Then $\mathrm{dim} X\setminus U < \mathrm{dim} X$.

If $X$ is irreducible, I know how to show that the inequality holds. But I can't use the same argument if I don't have that each irreducible component of $X\setminus U$ is in some $X_i$. Anyone know if is it true? Any hints?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: maybe you could write down the proof of the inequality for irreducible case. It is of interest to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

Write $X = \cup_i X_i$ where $X_i$ are the irreducible components. Assuming $X$ is noetherian, there are finitely many irreducible components. Thus $V_i = X_i \setminus (\cup_{j\neq i} X_j)$ is an open subset, and if $U$ is dense, it must meet each $V_i$. But then $U\cap V_i$ is a nonempty open subset of $V_i$, so it is dense (or, equivalently, $X_i \cap (X\setminus U)$ is a proper closed subset of $X_i$) and you may apply the statement for irreducibles to finish the proof.

Comment: Applying the statement we have that $\mathrm{dim} X_i\cap (X\setminus U)<\mathrm{dim} X_i$, and then  $\max_i\mathrm{dim} X_i\cap (X\setminus U)<\max_j\mathrm{dim} X_j=\mathrm{dim}X$. But why $\max_{i}\mathrm{dim} X_i\cap (X\setminus U)=\mathrm{dim} X\setminus U$? Is $X\setminus U=\cup_i X_i\cap (X\setminus U)$ the irreducible decomposition of $X\setminus U$? If yes, how can I show that each $X_i\cap (X\setminus U)$ is irreducible?

Comment: You do not need to show that each $X_i\cap (X\setminus U)$ is irreducible, and in fact it need not be true. The complement of any proper closed subset of an irreducible topological space is a dense open, and you may use the statement you have said you know how to prove.